# Как для графика barh название строки set_ylabel сделать такими же как название строк set_ylabel в графике barplot в matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Это мой код:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(world_region()), 3, figsize=(30, 50))

row = 0
colume = 0

i = 0 # переменная для перебора названий региона

for region in list_df_regions():     
    
    region = region.loc[:]

    #Гистограмма
    sectors = region['sector'].value_counts()
    sns.barplot(ax=axes[row,colume], y=sectors.index, x=sectors.values, alpha=.6)
    axes[row,colume].set_title("Сектора в регионе {}".format(world_region()[i]), pad=30, fontsize=25)
    axes[row,colume].set_xlabel('Количество заявок', color = 'red', fontsize=20)
    axes[row,colume].set_ylabel('Сектора', color = 'red', fontsize=20)
    axes[row, colume].tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=22)
    axes[row, colume].tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=22)

    # Круговая диаграмма
    colume += 1
    cdict = {'male': 'dodgerblue', 'female': 'orange', 'group': 'green'}
    region['borrower_genders']=[elem if elem in ['female', 'male'] else 'group' for elem in region['borrower_genders']]
    borrowers = region['borrower_genders'].value_counts()
    explode = []
    for k in borrowers:
        explode.append(.05)
    axes[row, colume].set_title("Гендерно-групповое\n распределение заемщиков в регионе\n {}".format(world_region()[i]), pad=30,
                               fontsize=25)
    colors = [cdict[x] for x in borrowers.index]
    plot = borrowers.plot.pie(ax=axes[row, colume],  colors = colors, autopct='%0.1f%%',  labels=None, explode=explode, 
                              shadow = True , labeldistance=1, radius=1.2, fontsize=20)
    axes[row, colume].legend(labels=borrowers.index, loc=(1, .7), fontsize=22)
    axes[row, colume].get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    plt.tight_layout(pad=10, w_pad=10)
    
    # Гистограмма гендерного распределения в секторах
    df_gender_by_sector = region[region['sector'].isin(sectors.index.values)]\
    .groupby(['sector', 'borrower_genders'])['borrower_genders']\
    .count()\
    .groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: 100 * x / x.sum())\
    .unstack('borrower_genders')\
    .fillna(0)\
    .sort_values(by=['male', 'female'])[:]

    df_gender_by_sector = df_gender_by_sector[['male', 'female', 'group']]
    
    colume += 1
    region['borrower_genders']=[elem if elem in ['female', 'male'] else 'group' for elem in region['borrower_genders']]
       
    plot = df_gender_by_sector.plot.barh(ax=axes[row, colume], stacked=True)
    axes[row, colume].set_title("Гендерно-групповое распределение заемщиков\n по секторам в регионе\n {}"
                                .format(world_region()[i]), pad=30, fontsize=25)
    axes[row,colume].set_ylabel('Сектора', color = 'red', fontsize=20)
    axes[row, colume].get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    axes[row, colume].tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=22)
    axes[row, colume].legend(loc=2, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), fontsize=22)
    
    i+=1
    row+=1
    colume=0
    
plt.show()
```

Я получаю вот такие графики.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно сделать так, чтобы названия регионов на двух графиках были расположены напротив друг друга?

Comment: не могли бы вы как-то показать изображение, которое вы хотите получить.

Comment: Хочу получить графики, которые будет удобно читать. То есть чтобы сектор Services графика "Гендерно-групповое распределение заемщиков по секторам в регионе South Asia" был также на первом месте как на графике "Сектора региона South Asia".